# `sudo -u user script` does not even have access to /bin/sleep

Tags: shell-script, sudo

When running the script `bla` with

```
sudo -u otheruser ./bla
```

I get an output indicating that this script is run such that no external commands are available:

```
otheruser
./bla: line 3: /bin/sleep: Permission denied
./bla: line 4: /bin/sleep: Permission denied
```

The script itself is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $USER
/bin/sleep 1
sleep 1
```

The last error message even seems to indicate that it is not really a bash that is running but rather a shell that does not have sleep as a built in command, since otherwise it would not complain about `/bin/sleep`.

Reading the docs, I find NOEXEC, which would possibly fit the bill, but /etc/sudoers has not hint on NOEXEC.

Am I on the right track with NOEXEC? If yes, why could it be active if it is not in `/etc/sudoers` and `sudo -V` also has no hint towards it?

EDIT: as asked in the comments, the output of `sudo -l -l`:

```
Matching Defaults entries for xxxxx on this host:
    always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS XDG_SESSION_COOKIE", targetpw, !authenticate, noexec, syslog=local5, env_reset,
    always_set_home

User xxxxx may run the following commands on this host:

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
ALL

LDAP Role: CENSORED
    RunAsUsers: root
    Options: !noexec
    Commands:
/bin/su - solr

LDAP Role: T-SOLRSEARCH
    RunAsUsers: root
    Options: !noexec
    Commands:
ALL
```

Ok, here we have a `!noexec`. What's the deal with the '!'?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output of `sudo -l -l` (yes, that's -l (lower case L) twice, `-ll` works too).

Comment: Output of `ls -l /bin/sleep` ?

Comment: Currently I have no access to the machine to list /bin/sleep, but we replaced sudo with su and then it works, so access rights should be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Matching Defaults entries for xxxxx on this host:
>     …, noexec, …
> ```

The user `xxxxx` is allowed to run any program, but this program isn't allowed to run any other program. There are exceptions when running commands as root. As a security restriction, this makes no sense: if you can run *any* program then you can e.g. run `passwd` and change the password on the root account; if you can run programs as root then you can run programs as any user. So this is a misconfiguration.

Look for a `Defaults` line in `/etc/sudoers` or in files under `/etc/sudoers.d` containing the `noexec` option.

In `!noexec`, `!` is a negation: this disables the `noexec` option.

Comment: This negation makes it even stranger then, because the user should then be able to run /bin/sleep from a shell script. But he can't. Hmm, strange.

Comment: @Harald The negation is only in rules where the target user is `root`, so it doesn't apply here since the target user is `otheruser`.